# Разница "я это хочу" и "мне это нужно"

Tags: смысл

Интуитивно чувствую, что в этих формулировках смысловая разница есть. И заключается она не только в прихоти (мол, в первом случае — действительно, прихоть, а во втором — необходимость), но в чем-то еще. Но сформулировать никак не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласна, что есть  противопоставление прихоть - необходимость(хочу коньки-мне нужны коньки), но,по-моему, есть ещё противопоставления: желание- требование (хочу, чтобы ты пришёл-нужно, чтобы ты пришёл); субъективное желание,требование-объективная необходимость(Хочу, чтобы Вы это сделали-это нужно сделать).

"нужно" имеет два значения:1.следует,полезно, необходимо,( нужно, чтобы все явились)2. требуется, следует иметь(мне нужно 5 рублей)

Comment: >>есть противопоставление прихоть - необходимость..., но,по-моему, есть ещё противопоставления: желание- требование...; субъективное желание,требование-объективная необходимость...  
  
Разве первое не покрывает с лихвой второе и третье?!

Comment: Но автору нужны ОТТЕНКИ смысла. Субъективное желание не всегда прихоть, Вы же привели пример с "хочу пить", а можно хотеть конфеты и мороженое - это прихоть. Я хочу пойти на каток-желание,(но не прихоть), мне нужно на каток-объективное требование. Это уже оттенки.

Comment: Оттенки - да, но помимо тех, которые содержаться в "главной разнице".
А так-то можно понапридумывать много всего. 
Из серии: жила-была простая *шведская* семья: папа, мама, брат с сестрой и малыш, который *хотел* только собаку.

Comment: Позвольте заметить, что мы отвечаем автору вопроса, который ищет разницу оттенков смысла:" И заключается она не только в прихоти..." Вот я и подсказываю:желание-необходимость, субъективность-объективность. А прихоть-один из оттенков желания и субъективности.

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить о смысле, то помимо Вами же сформулированной никакой "другой разницы" я тут не вижу. Может, конечно, она и есть, но на фоне главного искать еще чего-то просто не хочется - да и бессмысленно.
Впрочем, попробуйте подобрать синонимы к каждому выражению, может поймете, что Вы хотите сказать.

Кстати, "хочу" - не обязательно прихоть.

Я хочу пить = мне нужна вода. Какая уж тут прихоть...